# Crashing code(pointers C99)

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand why that code crash:(CodeBlocks C99)

```
int a;
int **b=0;
*b=&a;
```

I know that **b is of type* int* and &a is also int* so what's the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take this apart:

```
int a; /* make a an integer, assuming this is in a function on the stack */
int **b=0; /* make b a pointer to a pointer to an integer, but make it point to 0 */
*b=&a; /* store the address of a at the address pointed to by b, which is 0 */
```

IE you are explicitly writing the address of `a` to a zero location. The problem is not type compatibility, it's that you are trying to store something at location zero, which will cause a seg fault.

To fix it do something like:

```
int a; /* make a an integer, assuming this is in a function on the stack */
int *c = 0; /* make an integer pointer, initialise it to NULL */
int **b=&c; /* make b a pointer to a pointer to an integer, make it point to c */
*b=&a; /* store the address of a at the address pointed to by b, which is c */
```

Answer (score 2):

b points to a pointer,   you point the pointer to 0 / NULL, meaning when you do *b =   you are assigning the value to address 0 which will die on most OSs  ( on embedded systems this can be valid depending on the processor)

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing the NULL-Pointer. `b` points to NULL and in the next line you are dereferencing it and assigning it a new value.

You are not allowed to write to memory you don't own, and you are *especially* not allowed to write to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set pointers to values like that (*b=&a) because they are at the time not pointing to anything; in order to set their value they must be pointing to something.

```
int a;
int *tmp;
int **b = &tmp;
*b = &a; //this should work because you are setting a real variable (in this case tmp) to &a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `int **b=0` is a *pointer* to `int *`, that is initialized to `NULL`, and isn't pointing at an allocated storage area. When you write to `*b`, you are attempting to dereference a null pointer, which is illegal.

If you were to allocate storage, for example using `b=malloc(sizeof(*b))`, you would then be able to write into the area pointer at by `b` using `*b=&a`, because then `*b` would be a valid address to write into.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
  int a;
  int **b = (int**)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
  *b = &a;
  free(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Your `*b = &a` has the same effect of `b[0] = &a`.

Comment: @ASKASK Syntax is different for this?  I believe the underlying concept is the same.

Comment: edit your answer so it doesn't have the C++,  eg, delete everything up until the first {  and delete the new ( use malloc if you want to present this idea )

Comment: the underlying principal is the same it is just that in regular C you dont have stuff like "new int*" or "delete b"

Comment: @Downvoter, please give me a reason? Thanks, anything wrong about my hints??

Comment: You probably should allocate more than 1 byte.